# Unix permissions for Craft

Tags: installation, permissions

Quick preface - i'm a new to managing my own servers. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache. I ran into some problems setting up Craft which i was hoping someone might be able to shed a bit of light on what i got wrong. I have a user with sudo privileges, lets say 'user1'.

I used a simple PHP script to find out what user PHP is running as:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

Which came out as 'www-data'. In terminal as 'user1' i created a new group 'craftpermissions' and added 'user1' and 'www-data' to this group. I then set the group 'craftpermissions' as the owner of the following directories:

```
/craft/app/
/craft/config/
/craft/storage/
```

I then set permissions on those three folders to 775 using:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/myvirtualhostaddress/craft/app/
```

However when i visited `mydomainname.com/index.php/admin/` i still got the error saying php could not write to the /config folder.

In the end i set permissions on the folder to 777 so i could crack on with installation and it worked fine, but i'd like to do it properly as i think 777 is a bit of a no-no? Or does it not matter too much if craft folder is one directory above my web root?

Any guidance much appreciated.

**EDIT**

for `/craft/app` everything is owned by craftpermissions except `..` which is owned by the group created when i made user1:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 user1 user1 4096 Aug 25 06:44 ..
```

does this refer to the directory above it? When i run on /craft/storage/ it appears as:

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 user1 craftpermissions 4096 Aug 25 09:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user1 user1       4096 Aug 25 06:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data   www-data         4096 Aug 25 09:19 runtime.
```

`/craft/config` appears as

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 user1 craftpermissions 4096 Aug 25 09:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user1 user1       4096 Aug 25 06:44 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 craftpermissions  671 Aug 25 06:44 db.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 craftpermissions  220 Aug 25 06:44 general.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data   www-data          255 Aug 25 09:19 license.key
drwxrwxrwx 2 user1 craftpermissions 4096 Aug 25 06:45 redactor
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 craftpermissions  844 Aug 25 06:44 routes.php
```

Comment: You definitely don't want to run with 777 in a production environment. When you `ls -al`, what user:group currently owns `craft/app`, `craft/storage` and `craft/config`?

Comment: i've edited my post above

Comment: You might have to `service apache2 restart` after adding `www-data` to the group. If that doesn't work - anything interesting in the Apache logs? Also - any reason why you're not just `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/myvirtualhostaddress`?

Comment: Just to narrow things down if you `chown` those files to `www-data:www-data`, do the 755 permissions work then?

Comment: i chown'd the `/app`,`/storage` and `/config` folders to www-data:www-data, and set permissions to 755 and it worked fine - thanks for the suggestion. is it ok to do it this way (having directories owned by www-data), or are there any drawbacks? is the best way to figure out how to do it with groups? i think i've probably just not fully understood how the relationships between groups / users works. am i understanding right that if group X is assigned through chown to a directory, any user in the group X should be able to read/write/execute with 775 (regardless of assigned user through chown)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this helps, but here is how I (attempt) to manage deployments/installs.

I first create a user so I'm not using the root account. I tie that user to the apache user group. We'll call him 'user1'.

I use beanstalk to deploy, and the deployment credentials are for 'user1'.

Once all of the files have deployed for the first time, I'll log into the server via terminal, and `chown` the project directory: `chown -R user1:apache`

Next, I'll make sure everything has the correct permissions: `chmod -R 754 mysite.com`

Next, I know that Craft needs to be able to write to:

- /craft/app
- /craft/config
- /craft/storage

I will chmod those directories to 774. `chmod -R 774`. Since 'user1' belongs to apache, it can read/write to the appropriate directories.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Probably need to be able to write to any folder you have setup as an asset source as well...

Comment: ^ This too... :)

Comment: when you say "tie the user to the apache user group"...how do you do that?

Comment: @DavidRhoden this part: `chown -R user1:apache`   in this case, I am saying  modify the file/folder so that `user1` is the owner and it belongs to the `apache` group